# Content generator to generate a description for entries

Tags: documentation-generator

I'm working on an automated solution to help speed up my daily tasks. I'm in the design phase currently, so things are still being worked out in how this is exactly going to work, however, I am trying to reduce the time I spend coming up with descriptions & titles for items. A great example would be to generate a description & title of a car that will be posted on craigslist or eBay.

What I am looking for, is a content generator, or something that will take in data such as make/model/year/condition/add-ons and "comments" provided by the customer to generate and create a description and title of the product based on those data points provided.

Is there any software out there that can do something like this or any open source software that I could mod to do what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] and expand it with actual examples? The way I interpret is *given that my data contains items with meaning X,Y,Z, I want to have this data to flow into a template string with place holders for X, Y, Z*. And then you want to maintain templates, I assume. Describe some more, give estimated numbers, OS, desired input and output formats.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [First Draft](http://www.justoutsourcing.com/files/fd/first-draft-report-generator.html). First Draft's Report Generator does exactly what you're looking for and a bit more in terms of working with data. It not only inserts your descriptions where you want; it gives you the option of  ignoring certain columns and/or using your descriptions based on certain criteria too, such as if a cell contains or doesn't contain a certain value, or if a cell is higher or lesser than a certain value, etc.

[image: First Draft's Report Editor]

It's not open source, though.